# Create a new column containing the grepped string

Tags: r, string-matching

I have dataframe of 3500+ projects and I want to grep search for 40ish key words in `Project_Description` column. If `Project_Description` contains one or more of the keywords, I want to create a new column and label that project's row with the keyword(s).

How can I create an if statement that loops through my keywords and if the keyword(s) is found labels the proper row with the keyword(s)? Especially if the `Project_Description` probably contains more than one of the keywords?

So far I've been able to pull out the rows of projects that contain at least one of the key words in `Project_Description` column.

```
key_words <- c("who","what","when","where","why", etc...)

dataframe_key_words <- c()

for (i in 1:length(key_words)){
dataframe_key_words <- rbind(dataframe_key_words, dataframe_original[grep(key_words[i], dataframe_original$Project_Description), ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```r
library(data.table)
library(stringi)
key_words <- c("where", "why")
pat <- paste0("(", paste0(key_words, collapse = "|"), ")")
DT <- data.table(descr = c("where is the sample data? why do you do this?", 
                           "this doesn't have any of the keywords"))
DT[, kw := lapply(stri_match_all_regex(descr, pat), function(x) x[, 2])][]

#                                            descr        kw
# 1: where is the sample data? why do you do this? where,why
# 2:         this doesn't have any of the keywords        NA
```